# Is there a way to hide Milestone header from milestone tracker

Tags: service-cloud-console, casemilestone, service, entitlement-process

I want to hide "Milestone" header from Milestone time tracker .Is there a way to do it .
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way to do this
we can create 1 custom empty LWC component where we can override the css of this window where we can hide the header.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer is 'No' you cannot hide/remove milestone header as this is salesforce standard functionality.  However if you still need this you might need to build [custom component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_milestoneTracker.htm) and add it in lightning console.

Thanks